# Grunt task run one by one

Tags: gruntjs

Please help me.. I am new to grunt. I have to run grunt task one by one. When i execute the Grunt file i am trying to execute one by one ['clean', 'writefile','concat','requirejs'] since write file helps to create a dynamic json for requier.

When ever i execute first time grunt gives me error and at the second time it runs without error since the json file is created in the path. I tried grunt.task.run() but i couldn't get it

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
        'use strict';
        grunt.initConfig({

            // Before generating any new files, remove any previously-created files.
            clean: {
                tests: ['rjs/build.json','frontend-built']
            },
            writefile: {
                json_value: {
                    options: {
                        data: 'frontend/config.json'
                    },
                    src: 'rjs/value.hbs',
                    dest: 'rjs/build.json'
                }
            },
            requirejs: {
                compile: {
                    options:grunt.file.readJSON('rjs/build.json')
                }
            },
            concat: {
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'frontend/theme/css/theameA.css': ['frontend/theme/css/common/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/lib/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/theme_a/**/*.css'],
                        'frontend/theme/css/theameB.css': ['frontend/theme/css/common/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/lib/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/theme_b/**/*.css']

                    }
                }
            }

        });
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-writefile');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
        grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'writefile','concat','requirejs']);

    };
```

Comment: do you want to tell us what the error is?  we are bad at guessing

Comment: >> Error: Unable to read "rjs/build.json" file (Error code: ENOENT).
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Comment: I try to load dynamic json file for requrejs task options. But this json file is dynamically created by writefile task with the help of my project config json.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is that the config code is processed *before* the tasks run so even if it didn't error out, it wouldn't be the correct behavior.

Try this to set the requirejs config dynamically via another custom task:

```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {

    'use strict';
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Before generating any new files, remove any previously-created files.
        clean: {
            tests: ['rjs/build.json','frontend-built']
        },
        writefile: {
            json_value: {
                options: {
                    data: 'frontend/config.json'
                },
                src: 'rjs/value.hbs',
                dest: 'rjs/build.json'
            }
        },
        concat: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'frontend/theme/css/theameA.css': ['frontend/theme/css/common/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/lib/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/theme_a/**/*.css'],
                    'frontend/theme/css/theameB.css': ['frontend/theme/css/common/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/lib/**/*.css','frontend/theme/css/theme_b/**/*.css']

                }
            }
        }

    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-writefile');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
    grunt.registerTask('setRjsConfig', function() {
         grunt.config('requirejs.options.compile', grunt.file.readJSON('rjs/build.json'));
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'writefile','concat', 'setRjsConfig', 'requirejs']);

};
```